# Ignore specific patterns in line using sed

Tags: unix, sed, grep

I'm trying to grep the word which starts with `group` keyword & ends with `-wx` in the given line. Also I need to ignore the below words.

1. Starts with `default:group` and ends with `-wx`
2. `group::-wx`

My Findings

```
echo "# file: /test/test123 # owner: own # group: acct user::r--  group::r-x mask::rwx other::r-x default:user::r-- default:user:an:--x default:group::r-x default:group:fin:-wx default:mask::rwx default:other::r-x" | grep -o "group:[^ ]*-wx" | sed '/group::-wx/d';'/default:[^ ]*:[^ ]*-wx/d'
```

Actual result

```
fin:-wx
```

Expected result

```
<null>
```

Comment: Is this the expected format of your input?

Comment: @mnestorov : yes it is

Answer (score 0):

You already have a grep to select what you want, simply add grep statements to remove those you do not want.

Like so:

```
LINE="# file: /test/test123 # owner: own # group: acct user::r--  group::r-x mask::rwx other::r-x default:user::r-- default:user:an:--x default:group::r-x default:group:fin:-wx default:mask::rwx default:other::r-x"

echo $LINE | grep -o "group:[^ ]*-wx" \
           | grep -vo "default:group:[^ ]*-wx" \
           | grep -vo "group::-wx"
```

On my linux it returns nothing, which is what you expected.  I do not have other test samples, but I think this is ok.

Comment: Won't it also do the job if you just put a space infront of `grep -o " group:[^ ]]*-wx"`, since we don't want anything before the `group`

Comment: You can try it.  Looks promissing, I did not analyse the input that much.  The OP should specify if spaces could be tabs for example.  Then it would not work.  But we do not have that level of detail.

Comment: It works for sure, but you are correct to point out if there would be tabs or spaces or any other detail we are not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

As you are first extracting the substring `group:fin:-wx` out of
`default:group:fin:-wx` with `grep`, the following `sed` filter
`/default:[^ ]*:[^ ]*-wx/d` no longer works.

A workaround is to change the order of filtering:

```
str="# file: /test/test123 # owner: own # group: acct user::r--  group::r-x mask::rwx other::r-x default:user::r-- default:user:an:--x default:group::r-x default:group:fin:-wx default:mask::rwx default:other::r-x"
echo "$str" | sed -e 's/default:group:[^ ]*-wx//' -e 's/group::-wx//' | grep -o 'group:[^ ]*-wx'
```

As an alternative, if your `grep` supports `-P` option, you can make use of `positive lookbehind` as:

```
echo "$str" | grep -Po '(?<= )group:[^ ]*-wx' | sed -e '/group::-wx/d' -e '/default:[^ ]*:[^ ]*-wx/d'
```

The pattern `(?<= )` forces the pattern match preceded by a whitespace without
including it in the output.